# in cakephp, standing on a view, how to call an element, and use it inside a div created in the layout?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

In my layout cakephp I have 2 divs:

```
<div id="header"> 
</div>

<div id="sideBar">
</div>
```

The question is, standing on a view,
for example `index.ctp`, how can I call an element inside the div `sidebar` for exemple?

So how can I add an `element` inside a div created elsewhere?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the new and powerful view blocks:
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views.html#using-view-blocks

Answer (score 1):

Just like this:

```
<div id="sideBar">
    <?php echo $this->element('sideBar'); ?>
</div>
```

If you want to pass params:

```
<div id="sideBar">
    <?php echo $this->element('sideBar', array('param1' => $param1)); ?>
</div>
```